# How to add an item to magento breadcrumbs

Tags: php, magento, web, e-commerce

I want to display breadcrumbs while a use navigates my own module on the frontend of magento, the site already has the appropriate breadcrumb code in place thats used elsewhere as per standard magento breadcrumbs.

What do I need to do in my module to specify the current breadcrumb path?

I'd prefer to be able to do this programmatically rather than having to write something custom in the breadcrumbs phtml file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can call breadcrumbs like below in your custom block file in your `_prepareLayout` function.

```
if ($breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')) {
    $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('home', array('label'=>$helper->__('Home'), 'title'=>$helper->__('Go to Home Page'), 'link'=>Mage::getBaseUrl()));
    $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('product_list', array('label'=>$helper->__('Brands'), 'title'=>$helper->__('Brands'), 'link'=>Mage::getUrl('brands')));
    $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('product_detail', array('label'=>Mage::getModel('inic_brand/brand')->getBrandName($brand->getBrand(), Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()), 'title'=>$brand->getIdentifier()));
            }
```

hope this will be sure help to you.

Comment: What file does this code get added to or block? If I have a a page that the url ends with www.mywebsite.com/science/creams-renew-skin and the breadcrumbs now are currently only showing Home / creams-renew-skin but i would like them to reflect Home / science / creams-renew-skin how do i go about this? Thanks in advance.. i hope that makes sense.

Comment: if your page build with custom extension then go to controller's action

Answer (score 7):

You can call breadcrumbs also from xml in any custom modules layout.

```
<index_index...>   
 <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Home</label>
                    <title>Home</title>
                    <link>/</link>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Contacts</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Custom Page</label>
                    <title>Custom Page</title>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
        </reference>
</index_index...>
```