# set breadcrumb for Magento One Step Checkout page

Tags: magento

Sorry If my question is repeated or naive...

I am new to magento and My developer left in between...

I need to set up the breadcrumb link on this onestepcheckout page

http://epbitservices.com/demo/globalcart/demo/globalcart/us/index.php/checkout/onepage/

now, what I have tried is editing /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/onepagecheckout.xml and page.xml

but no success.. please help

This is my onepagecheckout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="2.2.4">

    <onepagecheckout_index_index translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout</label>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem" ifconfig="onepagecheckout/general/enabled"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/onepagecheckout.css</name></action>
        </reference>
<reference name="breadcrumbs"> 
            <action method="addCrumb"> 
            <name>home</name> 
                                        <params> 
                                            <label>Home</label> 
                                             <title>Home</title> 
                                            <link></link> 
                                        </params> 
                 </action>

                 <action method="addCrumb"> 
            <name>Onepage checkout</name> 
                                        <params> 
                                            <label>OnePage Checkout</label> 
                                             <title>OnePage Checkout</title> 
                                            <link>onepagecheckout</link> 
                                        </params> 
                 </action>
          </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage" name="onepagecheckout" template="onepagecheckout/onepagecheckout.phtml">
                <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer.login" template="onepagecheckout/login.phtml"/>
                <block type="customer/account_forgotpassword" name="customer.forgot" template="onepagecheckout/forgotpassword.phtml"/>

                <block type="onepagecheckout/onepage_billship" name="checkout.onepage.billing" as="billing.address" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/billing.phtml"/>
                <block type="onepagecheckout/onepage_billship" name="checkout.onepage.shipping" as="shipping.address" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/shipping.phtml"/>

                <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method" as="shipping.method" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml">
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available" as="available" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml"/>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_additional" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.additional" as="additional" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml"/>
                </block>

                <block type="checkout/onepage_payment" name="checkout.onepage.payment" as="payment.method" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/payment.phtml">
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
                        <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template></action>
                    </block>
                </block>

                <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/coupon.phtml"/>

                <block type="checkout/onepage_review" name="checkout.onepage.review" as="review" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/review.phtml">
                    <block type="onepagecheckout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="info" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
                        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>onepagecheckout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>onepagecheckout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>onepagecheckout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                        <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
                        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <block type="onepagecheckout/addresscandidates" name="checkout.addresscandidates" as="addresscandidates" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/address_candidates.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </onepagecheckout_index_index>

    <checkout_cart_index>    

        <reference name="checkout.cart.top_methods">
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="onepagecheckout/general/enabled"><name>checkout.cart.methods.onepage.top</name></action>
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="onepagecheckout/general/enabled"><name>checkout.cart.methods.onepage</name></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="checkout.cart.methods">
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="onepagecheckout/general/enabled"><name>checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom</name></action>
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="onepagecheckout/general/enabled"><name>checkout.cart.methods.onepage</name></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="checkout.cart.top_methods">            
            <block ifconfig="onepagecheckout/general/enabled" type="onepagecheckout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.fire" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
        </reference>

        <reference name="checkout.cart.methods">
            <block ifconfig="onepagecheckout/general/enabled" type="onepagecheckout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.fire" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>

    <onepagecheckout_index_updatecheckout>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.method" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
            <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
        <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/coupon.phtml"/>
         <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="checkout.shipping.method" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml"/>
        <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="checkout.review" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>onepagecheckout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>onepagecheckout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>onepagecheckout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before"/>
        </block>
        <block type="onepagecheckout/addresscandidates" name="checkout.addresscandidates" as="addresscandidates" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/address_candidates.phtml"/>
    </onepagecheckout_index_updatecheckout>

    <onepagecheckout_index_success translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </onepagecheckout_index_success>

    <onepagecheckout_index_failure translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_failure" name="checkout.failure" template="checkout/onepage/failure.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </onepagecheckout_index_failure>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Please used below codes-

```
  <onepagecheckout_index_index translate="label"> 
<label>One Page Checkout</label>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem" ifconfig="onepagecheckout/general/enabled"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/onepagecheckout.css</name></action>
        </reference>

     <reference name="breadcrumbs"> 
                <action method="addCrumb"> 
                <name>home</name> 
                                            <params> 
                                                <label>Home</label> 
                                                 <title>Home</title> 
                                                <link></link> 
                                            </params> 
                     </action>

                     <action method="addCrumb"> 
                <name>Onepage checkout</name> 
                                            <params> 
                                                <label>OnePage Checkout</label> 
                                                 <title>OnePage Checkout</title> 
                                                <link>{{baseSecureUrl}}onepagecheckout</link> 
                                            </params> 
                     </action>
              </reference>
    .......
```

reference link -'[http://web.gillady.com/magento/magento-add-breadcrumb-for-custom-module'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839151/how-to-add-an-item-to-magento-breadcrumbs)

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839151/how-to-add-an-item-to-magento-breadcrumbs): http://web.gillady.com/magento/magento-add-breadcrumb-for-custom-module or [How to add an item to magento breadcrumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839151/how-to-add-an-item-to-magento-breadcrumbs)

Comment: I added it in /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/onepagecheckout.xml

but it did`nt do the trick...

Comment: please give more details about onepage.xml

Comment: I edited my question and added the code for onepagecheckout.xml

Comment: Can please check again

Comment: This is My page link

[link]epbitservices.com/demo/globalcart/demo/globalcart/us/index.php/checkout/onepage/

Comment: Krisha ,what are  links you want to in onepage checkout

Comment: you need  add breadcrumbs in checkout.xml in checkout_onepage_index

Comment: I paste the required xml in checkout.xml and it works for me.