# Custom module url change

Tags: magento

I have created one custom module "Abc". So now my module url is like this

http://www.magento/abc/

But want to change my module url to "xyz" like

http://www.magento/xyz/

without changing in backend URL Rewrite Management. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find config.xml in your module, ideally in  Abc/etc/config.xml. Look router node:

```
<routers>
  <abc>
    <use>standard</use>
      <args>
        <module><Yourpack>_ABC</module>
        <frontName>abc</frontName>
      </args>
  </abc>
</routers>
```

Notice `<frontName>` name. Change the value anything you want. In your case it would be xyz. New xml looks like:

```
<routers>
  <abc>
    <use>standard</use>
      <args>
        <module><Yourpack>_ABC</module>
        <frontName>xyz</frontName>
      </args>
  </abc>
</routers>
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna for your quick reply. It's working for me and already try this before your reply. But getting another problem. I'm using manufacturer extension. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shop-by-brands-by-zeon-solutions.html

It's ok till www.magento/xyz but when i click on any brand like www.magento/xyz/dell/ it give 404 page not found error.

Comment: Accept the answer if it worked for you. For `www.magento/xyz/dell/` to work you have to add custom router. Otherwise, you have to see it like  `www.magento/xyz/index/view/dell/`. Where `index` is name of your controller like `IndexController` and `view` is action name in `IndexController` function e.g. viewAction, detailAction. Make sure you change `view` with right view name

Comment: There is already one router in Controller directory. Do i need to create new one? IF yes what changes i need to do in it?

Comment: Thanks Krishna i changed in router and now its working.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can i change this in breadcrumbs as well?

Comment: Breadcrumbs, look add this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839151/how-to-add-an-item-to-magento-breadcrumbs